# TextBox and a Button; can they be used to execute malicious code? (WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Let's say that we have a Form with a Button and a TextBox on it. The purpose of this app is to display a MessageBox containing the text written into the TextBox when the Button is clicked.

Is there anyway that somebody knowledgeable enough can perform malicious actions by writing code into the TextBox, or perform actions that were not a part of the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not if that's is the only thing it does.

If your textbox was to be used with building a SQL query.. that's another story.. but if all its doing is being shown in a `MessageBox`.. it's completely safe.

They cannot run random code either. That needs to be put through some sort of compilation process.. which doesn't happen in a `string` field such as the `MessageBox` caption/title.

Comment: Thank you Simon, I will accept the answer when the Timer runs out.